# limit size folder

Tags: linux

I would like to limit a folder space (in a shell script UNIX):
when the folder exceeds the maximum size, I have to remove the oldest files
How to do this and how to make it running all the time?

thanks for help

Comment: Question is not SELinux relevant at all. Honest, it is not relevant for StackOverflow too, rather for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your task into smaller parts:

1. Get the names of all the files in a directory
2. Get the timestamp and size for each of these files
3. Sort the files by time and select the oldest files to delete such that the remaining size does not exceed your maximum
4. Delete the files selected in step 3
5. Combine the above steps into a script that can be run as a single command
6. Add this script to a crontab so that it is run regularly

Hopefully this helps.